# Possible to Change Column Default Value on Libraries through Workflow?

Tags: workflow, document-library, designer-workflow, default-value

I have a list called IT Projects. Each item in this list is linked to Project.aspx with a different Query String passed in to filter the page depending one which project you click on. I also have a document library called Project Documents. Within that library, I have a folder for each project in IT Projects. Whenever a new item in IT Projects is created, a designer workflow kicks off to create a new folder for that project.

E.G.:

1. 00test item is created in IT Projects list.
2. 00test folder is created in Project Documents library.
3. 00test item's URL is linked to ../Project.aspx?ProjectName=00test and library location is linked to ../Project Documents/00test

The only problem I have which this solution is that when a new item is created, I need to manually assign a column default value on the newly created folder (00test in this example). Is there a to have this done through workflow or a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to edit the actual object using the SPSite object to change the fields of the list..